# Oracle 12c - Replace characters in string with nothing

Tags: oracle, select, oracle12c

I am trying to replace dashes with a space and apostrophes with nothing from a column that is defined as VARCHAR2(6), however my method is replacing them both with spaces up to the 6 characters.

Examples `"ABC-"` and `"ABC'"` need to be converted to `"ABC "` and `"ABC"` respectively.

I am using the following:

```
select UPPER(RPAD(REPLACE(REPLACE(NVL('ABC-',' '),'-',' '),'''',''), 6,' '))
from dual
```

This is returning `"ABC   "` but should return `"ABC "`

```
select UPPER(RPAD(REPLACE(REPLACE(NVL('ABC''',' '),'-',' '),'''',''), 6,' '))
from dual
```

And this is returning `"ABC   "` but should return `"ABC"`

Comment: What do you think the `rpad(,,,, 6, ' ')` is doing?

Comment: @AlexPoole When I remove the space from that, the result is still the same for some reason.

Comment: The default is a space anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure I am understanding your point, sorry it has been a long day.

Comment: [If you do not specify *expr2*, then it defaults to a single blank.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/RPAD.html). You are telling it to pad the value, so I'm not sure why you are surprised that it is doing that.

Comment: `rpad('ABC',6)` is the same thing as `rpad('ABC',6,' ')` because `' '` is the default pad character. Either way it pads to length 6, which you are getting, so I'm not seeing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
SQL>  select regexp_replace('ABC''','''','') from dual;

REG
---
ABC

SQL> select regexp_replace('ABC-','-',' ') from dual;

REGE
----
ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

use **TRANSLATE**  [official doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TRANSLATE.html)

```
TRANSLATE('abc-''','-''',' ')
```